# Identifying nonsequential rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following excel spreadsheet:

| CODE | ID |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| ABC | 2 |
| BCD | 1 |
| ABC | 4 |
| CDE | 1 |
| CDE | 2 |
| BCD | 5 |

I need to identify and create a list of each CODE in which there is an ID that does not directly follow the original sequence (in this example, ABC due to ABC4 and BCD due to BCD5) regardless of where in the table it lies. The initial ID's will be in sequence. When the CODE is updated (somewhere outside of this table), the table will generate a new row resulting in a nonsequential ID number.

Here's the brainstorming I've done so far:

- I create a dict and use each CODE in the table as the key and a list of every ID as it's value.
- Create some sort of IF statement that checks if the first value + 1 equals the second value. If false, save the CODE in a new list.

Am I on the right track in terms of thought process? I'm still struggling to identify when If/Else, While, and For loops are most appropriate. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What do you expect as outcome for this sample?

Comment: For this sample, I expect a list of: ABC, BCD

Answer (score 4):

Let us try `groupby` + `filter` ,notice since you with `pandas` try not use for loop

```
out = df.groupby('CODE').filter(lambda x : x['ID'].diff().dropna().ne(1).any())['CODE'].unique()
Out[239]: array(['ABC', 'BCD'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: You have to `.sort_values('ID')` before `groupby`

Comment: This is a great starting point. The output I'm getting based on your recommendation is a list of all the CODE's rather than those that have non-sequential ID's. My table has other columns with irrelevant information which may be what is causing the issue but I'll be digging into it on my end to see if I can figure it out. Thank you so much BENY.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `agg` but ensure your dataframe is sorted by `ID` columns else a sequence like [FGH (1, 3, 2)] will match

```
out = df.loc[df.sort_values('ID').groupby('CODE')['ID'].agg('diff').gt(1),
             'CODE'].tolist()
```

```
>>> out
['ABC', 'BCD']
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This code also looks promising and I am attempting to adjust it accordingly. It looks as though I'm running into the same issue that I mentioned in response to BENY's response. This has been a huge help. Thank you so much.